# Visual Studio Code problem matcher not working with custom output

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to get VS Code working with custom output. I've created a batch file which prints out:

```
warning:main.asm(5):Something is wrong
ERROR:main.asm(2):Something else is wrong
```

But when I run the following task:

```json
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\build.bat",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher":{
            "pattern":[
                {
                    "regexp": "^.*:(.*)\\(\\d+\\):(.+)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "message": 3,
                    "location": 0
            }]
        }
    }
]
```

I get the output that I'm expecting but I don't get any errors in the problems window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex isn't *quite* correct - since the parens around `\\(\\d+\\)` are escaped, it's not actually a capturing group. With an additional pair or parens it works for me:

```json
"regexp": "^.*:(.*)\\((\\d+)\\):(.+)$"
```

[image]